# Count time of same id records

Tags: mysql

Could anybody enlighten me with this question?
Let's assume I have a table with several records like this:

```
+--------------+--+
| ID room time |  |
+--------------+--+
| 1  1 10:00   |  |
| 2  2 10:01   |  |
| 3  1 10:01   |  |
| 4  1 10:02   |  |
| 5  1 10:03   |  |
| 6  1 10:04   |  |
| 7  2 10:02   |  |
+--------------+--+
```

I would like to get the count of time of room 1 only when it is continuous.
The result for this particular table should be:

```
+--------------+
| id room time |
+--------------+
| 1  1 00:03   |
+--------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a thought. Use `max`, `min` and their difference `as diff` with `having diff > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join a table against itself to achieve that:

Let's say the name of the table is tbl.  **My query won't quite be 100% right because I don't know what your data type is for time, but the concept is there**.

The A table must have an ID less than the one with the B id, but have the same room.

The C table represents records a check that there is no IDs between A and B for a different room, that's why C.ID is NULL

```
SELECT A.ROOM, MAX(B.TIME-A.TIME) FROM tbl A
    INNER JOIN tbl B on A.room=B.room and A.ID<B.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl C on A.room<>B.room and A.ID<C.ID and C.ID<B.ID
WHERE C.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY a.room
```